# In my code I want to use ng-click in ng-bind-html，How can I do this？

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

In　my code there is

```
$scope.open = function(url){
    window.open(url,  '__blank')
}
$scope.html = "<p>this is  <a href=\"#\" ng-click = \"open(\"http://www.face book.com\")\">facebook</a>"
```

then in the html page ,there is

```
<p ng-bind-html = "html"></p>
```

but when I click this div,it does not work that open a new window

Comment: `ng-bind-html` doesn't compile directives. There are modules available that will do it, or use your own directive or a delegated event handler

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this？Because I just started learning to use angularjs

Comment: For starters why are you using `ng-bind-html`? It is generally only used for user generated html such as from an editor. Otherwise you would use `ng-include` or a custom directive with it's own template

Comment: How could I use my directive to show the html?

Comment: there are lots of tutorials around regarding directives

Comment: thanks I will find that